# Display photo from library on QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, qlpreviewcontroller

I would like to use `QLPreviewController` to display an image that was previously selected from the library using `UIImagePickerController`. I can get its `url` like this:

```
let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
```

> This url starts with: assets-library://.

But when I display it in `QLPreviewController` it only shows a text like *JPEG Photo*, and not the actual image. Can this be done somehow?